# Persistent Axis2 Service Files

Tags: jboss7.x, apache-axis, jboss-eap-6

I deployed an instance on Axis2 within my JBoss EAP 6.2 server. However, the only way I can add my service files are through the online admin console. This is a problem because when I add them through the console they are added to a random folder within standalone/tmp/vfs. So when I stop and start my server again I lose my reference and I need to re-add them through the console. How can I set it up so that I do not need to re-add my service files every time I start my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepackage them inside your `war` under `/WEB-INF/services` so that they are automatically deployed with the war file.

e.g.

```
/WEB-INF
  /services
    /service_a.aar
    /service_b.aar
    /services.list
```

The `services.list` file in the same directory is a text file listing your aar files ... one per line

The `aar` files are just zipped Axis archives. They contain a META-INF directory with your wsdl, any xsd files and an Axis2 `services.xml` service configuration file describing the service.